# I tried to deploy a contract on Ropsten, but always get the following error

Tags: truffle, ropsten, rinkeby, infura

```
PS D:\nodejs\rff\metacoin> truffle --network ropsten migrate
Using network 'ropsten'.

Running migration: 1_initial_migration.js
  Deploying Migrations...
Error encountered, bailing. Network state unknown. Review successful transactions manually.
undefined
```

I then unbox the Metacoin and do truffle --network ropsten again. same error happened.
My truffle.js as following:

```
var HDWalletProvider = require("truffle-hdwallet-provider");

var mnemonic = "<My Mneomonic>";


module.exports = {
  networks: {
    rinkeby: {
      host: "127.0.0.1", // Connect to geth on the specified
      port: 8545,
      from: "0xec14efb50fd9108a567b007479bd3345300d8374", // default address to use for any transaction Truffle makes during migrations
      network_id: 4,
      gas: 4612388 // Gas limit used for deploys
    },

    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 8545,
      network_id: "*" // Match any network id
    },

    test: {
      gas: 6721975,
      gasPrice: 0,
      host: '127.0.0.1',
      port: 8545,
      network_id: '*' // Match any network id
    },

    ropsten: {
      from: "0x5FBC4Dde3019f7d93AA9c2b59E5537F3Fb1210df",
      gas: 6721975,
      gasPrice: 2,
      provider: new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, "https://ropsten.infura.io/<My token>"),      
      network_id: 3
    }
  }
}
```

I also tried Rinkeby and testnet. everthing goes well. then I try Rinkeby with provider:'https://rinkeby.infura.io/, got the same error. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Your gas price for Ropsten is too low. I'd suggest to use around 10 Gwei or more (1 Gwei ~ "1000000000" wei).

Also gas limit on Ropsten is 4.7M if you indicate more the transaction will not be accepted, even if you do not use all.